# How to access Google's research

Tags: phd, research-process

My PhD research is about AI and the topic I choose is relatively new.

As far as I know, the only organisation that has worked on that area is Google.

by searching this topic there wasn't enough info of that it was done, techniques, methodology, statistics, etc.

I wonder if there is a certain process to follow so I can get access to Google's research?

Comment: Probably apply for a job there, and sign their NDAs

Comment: @AzorAhai will be more than happy to get a job there but I have doubts about the NDA as it is going to be in my research and published !

Comment: IBM and the computers / software for the chess competitions...

Comment: @SolarMike What does your comment mean?

Comment: @JiK it means that I don't think it is only Google doing AI...

Comment: @SolarMike _"My PhD research is about AI and the topic I choose is relatively new"_ This does not mean OP claims AI as a topic is relatively new. It means that the topic of OP's PhD research is within AI and is relatively new.

Comment: @JiK Think the answer is more than relevant... also see https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/20-years-after-deep-blue-how-ai-has-advanced-since-conquering-chess/

Comment: @SolarMike The asker is researching _some specific topic in AI_. They haven't said what it is, but they believe that Google is the only organization to have done research _on that specific topic_. How can you suggest that this belief is false when you don't even know what the topic is?

Comment: @DavidRicherby so are you suggesting that the question is off-topic as it is too broad? I merely suggested that others may well be working on that topic...

Comment: @SolarMike The specific (sub-)topic is never mentioned by OP. Google and IBM are not the same entity, just because they both do research in AI does not mean they do exactly the same things, especially when it comes to new topics like the one OP is interested in. I also fail to see the relevancy of your first comment and the linked article. The only thing the article seems to prove is that IBM is doing research in AI which no one has denied.

Comment: @SolarMike The question is very specific: _How does one get access to Google's research?_ The topic of OP's research is just background information to motivate why they want access to Google's research.

Comment: @SolarMike No, I'm not suggesting that the question is too broad, and I don't understand why you think I am.

Comment: @JiK Thanks, my PhD is not about AI in general, it is about a specific topic within AI that has not been researched yet ( or I could not find any material about it yet except with google) but they did not release the research, techniques and methodologies. I contacted google yesterday and they adviced that whatever published in this website is https://ai.google/research/pubs/ is what they can release if it is not there then they wont release. not sure in this case if I do my research will still that be considered addition to the field although it is done by google but not yet released!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Google's publications are available here: https://ai.google/research/pubs.

Comment: I checked that link already, nothing on the research topic

Comment: Then either they haven't worked on your topic or they want to keep it secret. It's a private company, they do what they want with their research and sometimes they might want to keep a commercial advantage to themselves ;)

Answer (score 7):

If Google haven't made this particular research public, you'll need to talk to them about it. They might not want to say anything. They might only be prepared to talk under an NDA. If so, your university will have policies for dealing with this kind of thing. As with all things PhD-related, your advisor's job is to advise you about this.  It's very common for research with commercial partners to have this kind of restriction, especially in the natural sciences and engineering.

Note that it's perfectly possible to produce publications based on NDAed material. However, you have to be careful not to disclose the things you said you wouldn't disclose, and you may need to clear the paper with Google before submitting it anywhere.

Comment: Or if you don't want an NDA, go buy Google. No one owes any researcher their secrets. If you want them, cough up.

Comment: +1 This is great advice. The researchers at Google are just as any other researchers. They very likely *want* to talk about their research with researchers at other institutions. They just have a different funding arrangement which places its restrictions, but they will happily try to work within them.

Comment: Also, to my best knowledge in big companies research results are confidential by default and *sometimes* the only reason for not publishing them is lack of  motivation to go through the paperwork needed to make them non-confidential, but interest by a PhD student might very well be motivation enough.